# Java Keccak-256 implementation incorrect hash on zero byte message

Tags: java, cryptography, keccak

I have been trying to write my own implementation of Keccak-256 cryptographic hash function in Java. I have been using [Keccak specifications summary](https://keccak.team/keccak_specs_summary.html) and their [Implementation Guide](https://keccak.team/files/Keccak-implementation-3.2.pdf) for reference. I want to test my implementation using a zero length input. According to [this](https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/keccak_256.html) online tool. The zero length input should have a hash of: `C5D2460186F7233C927E7DB2DCC703C0E500B653CA82273B7BFAD8045D85A470` but my hash is something else.

My code is located here on [Github](https://github.com/acedogblast/Keccak-256).
My thoughts are that I must have done something wrong on the padding of the message(that is all that gets hashed) or something on byte order in my conversion of byte[] to longs and back, or the absorbing/squeezing phase. In my implementation I only need `keccak-f[1600]` which means there is only 64bits in each lane and that each block is 1088 bits or 136 bytes. I chose to use a five-by-five 2D array of longs to represent the state in my code.

Using a zero byte message means that there should only be one block of 136 bytes which should be all just padding. According to [this post](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/12720/keccak-padding-implementation-and-bit-ordering) since keccak uses little-endian my padding should be in this order of bytes:

```
byte[] p = new byte[136];
p[7] = (byte) 0x01;
p[135] = (byte) 0x80;
```

I have looked at someone else's [implementation](https://gitlab.com/Bobulous/Cryptography) but I can't seem to find out where my error is.

This is the sponge function:

```
public byte[] keccak(byte[] Mbytes, int r, int c) { // r should be 1088 and c should be 512 for Keccack-256
    // Padding
    byte[] paddedMessage = concatBytes(Mbytes, pad(r, Mbytes.length));
    System.out.println("Padded Message size: " + paddedMessage.length);

    // Initialize State
    A = new long[5][5];

    // Break up message into blocks r bits or 136 bytes
    byte[] block = new byte[136];
    int n = paddedMessage.length / block.length; // number of blocks
    System.out.println("Blocks: " + n);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { // For each block
        //set block values
        for (int j = 0; j < block.length; j++) {
            block[j] = paddedMessage[i * block.length + j];
        }
        printBlock(block);

        // Fill state
        for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < 5; y++) {
                int index = x + 5 * y;
                if (index < r/w) {
                    long value = decodeLELong(block, index * 8);
                    System.out.println(value + " index: " + index);
                    A[x][y] = A[x][y] ^ value;
                    A = keccakF1600(A);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    byte[] output = new byte[0]; // Size should be 256 bits/Z
    int bytesFilled = 0;
    for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < 5; y++) {
            int index = x+5*y;
            if (index < r/w) {
                if (bytesFilled < 136) {
                    // Take out a long from state and concat it to output.
                    output = concatBytes(output, encodeLELong(A[x][y]));
                    bytesFilled += 8;
                    A = keccakF1600(A);
                }
            }
            if (bytesFilled == 32) {
                //System.out.println("Finished Hash");
                return output;
            }
        }
    }

    return output;
}
```

This is my pad function:

```
 private byte[] pad(int x, int m) { // x/size should be 1088 or 136 bytes
    byte[] p = null;
    int q = 136 - (m % 136); // number of padding bytes
    //System.out.println("Pad q: " + q + "  m: " + m);
    if(q == 136) { // Whole block is padding
        p = new byte[136];
        p[7] = (byte) 0x01;
        p[135] = (byte) 0x80;
    }
    else { // Ignore for now
        p = new byte[q];
        p[0] = 1;
    }
    return p;
}
```

And this is my code for the keccak permutation:

```
public long[][] keccakF1600(long[][] A) { // KECCAK-f where b = 1600
    for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++) { // 24 Rounds
        A = Round1600(A, RC[i]);
    }
    return A;
}

private long[][] Round1600(long[][] A, long rc) {
    // θ Step
    long[] C = new long[5];
    for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
        C[x] = A[x][0] ^ A[x][1]^ A[x][2] ^ A[x][3] ^ A[x][4];
    }

    long[] D = new long[5];
    for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
        D[x] = C[(x + 4) % 5] ^ Long.rotateLeft(C[(x + 1) % 5], 1);
    }
    for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < 5; y++) {
            A[x][y] = A[x][y] ^ D[x];
        }
    }

    // ρ and π steps
    long[][] B = new long[5][5];
    for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < 5; y++) {
            B[y][(2 * x + 3 * y) % 5] = Long.rotateLeft(A[x][y], rot_offset(x,y));
        }
    }

    // χ step
    for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < 5; y++) {
            A[x][y] = B[x][y] ^ ((~B[(x+1) % 5][y]) & B[(x+2) % 5][y]);
        }
    }

    // ι step
    A[0][0] = A[0][0] ^ rc;

    return A;
}


private int rot_offset(int x, int y) {
    switch (x){
        case 0:
            switch (y) {
                case 0:
                    return 0;
                case 1:
                    return 36;
                case 2:
                    return 3;
                case 3:
                    return 41;
                case 4:
                    return 18;
            }
        case 1:
            switch (y) {
                case 0:
                    return 1;
                case 1:
                    return 44;
                case 2:
                    return 10;
                case 3:
                    return 45;
                case 4:
                    return 2;
            }
        case 2:
            switch (y) {
                case 0:
                    return 62;
                case 1:
                    return 6;
                case 2:
                    return 43;
                case 3:
                    return 15;
                case 4:
                    return 61;
            }
        case 3:
            switch (y) {
                case 0:
                    return 28;
                case 1:
                    return 55;
                case 2:
                    return 25;
                case 3:
                    return 21;
                case 4:
                    return 56;
            }
        case 4:
            switch (y) {
                case 0:
                    return 27;
                case 1:
                    return 20;
                case 2:
                    return 39;
                case 3:
                    return 8;
                case 4:
                    return 14;
            }
    }
    System.out.println("Should not Happen!");
    return -1; // Should not happen!
}
```

And finally the helper metheods to convert byte[] to long and back:

```
public static long decodeLELong(byte[] buf, int off)
{
    return (buf[off + 0] & 0xFFL)
            | ((buf[off + 1] & 0xFFL) << 8)
            | ((buf[off + 2] & 0xFFL) << 16)
            | ((buf[off + 3] & 0xFFL) << 24)
            | ((buf[off + 4] & 0xFFL) << 32)
            | ((buf[off + 5] & 0xFFL) << 40)
            | ((buf[off + 6] & 0xFFL) << 48)
            | ((buf[off + 7] & 0xFFL) << 56);
}
public static byte[] encodeLELong(long val)
{
    byte[] buf = new byte[8];
    buf[0] = (byte)val;
    buf[1] = (byte)(val >>> 8);
    buf[2] = (byte)(val >>> 16);
    buf[3] = (byte)(val >>> 24);
    buf[4] = (byte)(val >>> 32);
    buf[5] = (byte)(val >>> 40);
    buf[6] = (byte)(val >>> 48);
    buf[7] = (byte)(val >>> 56);
    return buf;
}
```

Last helper method for concatBytes:

```
public static byte[] concatBytes(byte[] in1, byte[] in2) {
    byte[] output = new byte[in1.length + in2.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < in1.length; i++) {
        output[i] = in1[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < in2.length; i++) {
        output[i + in1.length] = in2[i];
    }
    return output;
}
```

Comment: In general you need to include the relevant parts of your code in your question. The problem with links to code is that the links eventually go dead, and when that happens the question just becomes another pollutant in the Stackoverflow archive. I understand it can be challenging to know what to post and what to leave out, just do your best. You may keep the link to Github, it's just that question should not be completely dependent on that link.

Comment: You want to set the high bit **of the high=LE-last byte** of the last word; thats `p[135]` not `p[128]`. I didn't look at the rest.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Good to know. I will edit the post to add other important parts of my code.

Comment: Ok I now know that my Round1600 function for the keccak permutation is correct since I have copied Bouncing Castle's code for the permutation into mine and got the same hash. This means that the error is somewhere in either the padding, absorption, or the squeeze phases.